# OpenSSH Server: Directive 'SyslogFacility' is not allowed within a Match block

Tags: configuration, aix, sshd, syslog

I want a specific matched User to have its 'ssh/scp' activities logged in an alternative facility. The current default is AUTH, but I'd like to log stuff for user 'dummy' to syslog Facility 'LOCAL2'. 
I've tried this in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, without success:

```
Match User dummy                
            SyslogFacility LOCAL2
```

I just get the following error message

> /etc/ssh/sshd_config line 125: Directive 'SyslogFacility' is not allowed within a Match block

Any suggestions here?

Comment: What documentations says it should work?

Comment: I didn't find anywhere inthe documentation, therefore I'm asking for suggestions or if I missed something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of OpenSSH's sshd, which is typically ahead of the OpenSSH version provided in AIX, does not support the SyslogFacility directive in a Match block, just as it says. The [sshd documentation](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config) says, for the **Match** directive:

> Only a subset of keywords may be used on the lines following a Match keyword. Available keywords are AcceptEnv, AllowAgentForwarding, AllowGroups, AllowStreamLocalForwarding, AllowTcpForwarding, AllowUsers, AuthenticationMethods, AuthorizedKeysCommand, AuthorizedKeysCommandUser, AuthorizedKeysFile, AuthorizedPrincipalsCommand, AuthorizedPrincipalsCommandUser, AuthorizedPrincipalsFile, Banner, ChrootDirectory, ClientAliveCountMax, ClientAliveInterval, DenyGroups, DenyUsers, ForceCommand, GatewayPorts, GSSAPIAuthentication, HostbasedAcceptedKeyTypes, HostbasedAuthentication, HostbasedUsesNameFromPacketOnly, IPQoS, KbdInteractiveAuthentication, KerberosAuthentication, LogLevel, MaxAuthTries, MaxSessions, PasswordAuthentication, PermitEmptyPasswords, PermitListen, PermitOpen, PermitRootLogin, PermitTTY, PermitTunnel, PermitUserRC, PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes, PubkeyAuthentication, RekeyLimit, RevokedKeys, RDomain, SetEnv, StreamLocalBindMask, StreamLocalBindUnlink, TrustedUserCAKeys, X11DisplayOffset, X11Forwarding and X11UseLocalhost.

Not among them is SyslogFacility.

Comment: Well, that puts an end on my pursuit using OpenSSH.  Now I have to think about another method. If you have a suggestion please feel free to make it. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: You might look into the [auditing system](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1000212#8)